# replace certain parameter or entire URL

Tags: javascript

I need to replace the window URL with a new one based on a checkbox input. I'm trying to do this like so:

```
    // get checkbox value
    var selection = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val()
    // get current url
    var url = window.location.href;
    // prefix current URL with checkbox 
    url += '&site=' + selection + '&page=1';
    // debug line
    // console.log(url);
    // navigate to new URL
    location.replace(url);
```

I have a series of parameters at the end of my URL that looks like:

`mywebsite.com&site=main&page=1`

I either need to replace the entire URL, or *just the parameters* below:

**&site=main&page=1**

The key is in the last line. I've tried a few things this is the output:

Both `location.assign(url);` and `location.replace(url);` gives: `mywebsite.com&site=main&page=1&site=main&page=1`

`window.location.href()` seems to have the same behavior, it does not replace the entire URL.

What I don't understand is for `location.replace()` - sanity checking the behavior on [reading MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace), it quotes:

> The Location.replace() method replaces the current resource with the
>   one at the provided URL.

Ok, lets do it. Then this happens:

`http://mywebsite.com&site=main&page=1&site=main&page=1`

Beating to the punch - in the console log - it returns the correct URL parameters. So output in my console looks like:

`http://mywebsite.com&site=main&page=1`

Why is it not replacing the entire URL with the new one? How do you just replace the entire URL with a new one, or somehow just target the parameters? Regex?

Comment: `http://mywebsite.com&site=main&page=1` is not a valid URL, the first `&` should be a `?`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just build the URL you want and set that?

```
var url = 'http://mywebsite.com?site=' + selection + '&page=1';
location.href = url;
```

If you don't know what page you are on and that will be dynamic you can do:

```
var hostAndPath = location.host + location.pathname;
var selection = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
var url = hostAndPath + '?site=' + selection + '&page=1';
location.href = url;
```

Comment: The first one is what I would like to have done but I want to try to write something that will work on both localhost and the domain. Let me mess around with your second suggestion.